# Downgrading httpd on Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, httpd

I have a Fedora 16 server (installed in VirtualBox; host system is WinXP Pro, if it matters) that I'm trying to set up as a dev duplicate of an existing production server.  The prod server does a lot with manipulating URLs, so I need to get the two Apache servers as close to each other as I can.

The prod server runs http 2.0.63, but `yum install httpd` gives me 2.2.22, which doesn't like elements of 2.0.63's configuration files.  How do I install (using `yum` or anything else) an earlier version of httpd?

(My apologies for asking something that I could probably figure out via Google if I was looking for the right thing.  Unfortunately, I'm a software developer, not a sysadmin; I haven't been able to figure it out yet.  But if consensus is that this question is too Sysadmin 101 to add any value to the site, I'll delete it, no hard feelings.)

---

**Edit:**  The production server runs Fedora 8.  I have figured out this is a Very Bad Thing; Red Hat discontinued support for it in early 2009 ... shortly before our host provider (GoDaddy) put us on the box.  (In my defense, I only recently joined the company.)  Our production server is literally insecurable, and has been for as long as we've been running on it.  This is a data point in my ongoing project, Convince The Boss To Migrate To A Provider Who Isn't Bloody Horrible.

However, that's a medium-term project.  In the short term, my ability to do my job is crippled by the fact that I don't have a dev server.  So any advice to the effect of "So get your production environment out of the stone age already!" is 1) correct, 2) appreciated, and 3) pretty much useless to me.

Comment: What distro (and version) does the production server run?  CentOS4-ish?  Since you're just working with VMs, you may want to match the actual distro/version of the prod in your VM, rather than just run Fedora 16.

Comment: @cjc:  The production server runs Fedora 8. (Yes, Bad Thing, and a data point in my ongoing project Why We Need A New Host.) Setting up a Fed8 VirtualBox proved to be a much larger nuisance than I could deal with, as I couldn't figure out how to get PHP 5.3.6 (which the prod box uses) installed. (Red Hat discontinued support for Fed8 when PHP 5.2.6 was the latest.) Figured I'd try something newer (since we should go there eventually) and walk back anything that proved to be TOO new and improved.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the RPM for the version you need?  I don't think that version will be in the Fedora repos...  For the security fixes, it's probably better to plan to upgrade your other server.  (You won't run the old release in production, right?)

If you have a specific version you wish to install you need to specify it with `yum`.  First, erase the version that's installed `yum erase httpd` and reinstall with `yum localinstall /path/to/httpd.rpm`.

Comment: As I look for RPMs on the web, do I need one specifically compiled for Fedora 16?  Or can I get away with something more general than that?  And I'm not sure what we're asking; as mentioned, we are indeed running an old version of Apache/httpd in production.

Comment: You might be able to find a CentOS 4 repo with httpd-2.0.52 in it.  CentOS 4 went into de-support a couple of weeks ago, so that should be more findable than Fedora 8 (!).

Answer (score 0):

You can compile from source older version of apache but i think it's better to rewrite old configuration for newest Apache. Downgrading is not a good idea. Aplication are expanding and devoloping so downgrading isnt a solution its only simple bypass. Strongly recommend adapt old configuration to newest Apache. I think many people here will help you with that.

Comment: If this were a production environment, I'd agree with you completely.  But given that I'm trying to mimic an existing environment as best I can, running with two different configurations introduces variables I'd rather not have to deal with.  (For instance, if I try to solve a problem by doing something clever with Apache, I won't have any idea if it will work in production until I take it live.)

Comment: So compiling is what u are looking for ... but it is so old version that on Fedora 16 u can have a problems with compiling. Try install an older version of OS. I know that with Fedora 8 it will be dificult but maybe Fedora 11 or 12. Then try to install from rpm or compile your LAMP. And update your production env as fast as it is possible